# MS project 2013 - complex resource allocation

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I have used MSP before but not for years.  I have some long term tasks and I would like to allocate varying quantities of resource requirement (against single resources) each month on these tasks - can I do this in MS Project 2013 or any tips would be greatly appreciated.  It does not make sense on this project to break the tasks up (it is a 5 year project).

I have had a good look online and so far found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Task Usage or Resource usage view to manually contour the work for a resource over time.  Zoom out to show months and edit the total work per month.

Comment: thanks Julie - very helpful.  Using fixed duration, is there a simple way to add total (fixed) work per resource and allow MSP to just then spread it over the total duration of the task? (I have read many online tutorials and none cover this).

Comment: You can't have a task that is both fixed duration and fixed work.  If you create a fixed duration task and manually enter work (I'd use the Task Form in the lower pane), Project will spread the work evenly over the duration.  However, work may change if you  change resource assignment units.